# Working with conditionals in rails helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple helper in my rails app that sets a css `class` based on the state of an object, like:

```
<li class='<%= car_color(car.state) %>'><%= car.model %></li>
```

in the helper it's basically:

```
  module CarHelper
    def car_color(state)
      if state == 'in service'
        'car car-in-service'
      elsif state == 'in garage'
        'car car-in-garage'
      else
        'car'
      end
    end
  end
```

And it works fine for my usecase. However, how there's a new requirement that a `User` with a role of `customer` should not see the color coding that this helper creates.

My first thought was to do a check in the controller to see if the user should be able to see the color coding:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :is_customer?
  # bunch of restful stuff

  private
  def is_customer?
    @customer if current_user.roles.include? 'customer'
  end
end
```

And then in my helper, I can just add a line:

```
def car_color(color)
  return 'car' if @customer
end
```

This meets the requirements, but it smells to me. Now my helper has a dependency on `@customer` which is passed simply because it is an instance variable. An alternative would be to explicitly pass in a `user.role` to `car_color` or to wrap all of the calls to `car_color` in conditionals based on the user.role, which seems even worse.

Is there a way to help prepare this code for even more conditionals based on different user roles? My thought is to do something like:

```
  module CarHelper
    def car_color(args)
      set_color_for_role(args[:user_role]) if args[:user_role]
      set_color_for_state(args[:car_state]) if args[:car_state]
    end

    private
    def set_color_for_role(user_role)
      # stuff
    end
    def set_color_for_state(car_state)
      # stuff
    end
  end
```

I don't use rails helpers very often since I mostly work in angular and am wondering if I'm missing a cleaner OOP approach.

Comment: def car_color(role)
      COLORS = { "customer" => "RED", "admin" => "blue", "other" => "Green" }
      COLORS[role]
 end

You can also put this colors array in your users model and  can access here.

Comment: def car_state(state)
 if current_user.is_customer?
   "car"
 else
    "car car-#{state.gsub(' ', '-')}"
 end
end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any issue with checking the current user's roles in the helper method.

You could move the checking behaviour to the user model though which would make things cleaner (you may of course want to generalise this for multiple roles):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def is_customer?
    self.roles.include?('customer')
  end
end
```

Then in your helper you can just check if `current_user.is_customer?`

```
def car_color(state)
  if current_user.is_customer?
    'car'
  else
    if state == 'in service'
      'car car-in-service'
    elsif state == 'in garage'
      'car car-in-garage'
    else
      'car'
    end
  end
```

I find it useful sometimes to build up an array of the classes too which is often cleaner (I've thrown in a case too):

```
def car_color(state)
  car_classes = ['car']
  unless current_user.is_customer?
    car_classes << case state
      when 'in service' then 'car-in-service'
      when 'in garage' then 'car-in-garage'
    end
  end
  car_classes.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: i like this, but what happens when the helper is called like 30 ties in one view? Does `current_user.is_customer?` hit the db each time or is it cached somehow?

Comment: If you look in your logs you should see `CACHE (0.0ms)` against the second and subsequent queries for any `is_customer?` checks. This is because of query caching which is turned on by default. (See also: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/QueryCache.html#method-i-cache - can't find a really good link for it)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `draper` https://github.com/drapergem/draper gem and move this logic to decorator